# When i insert multi-records i face Identity_cash proplem

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I try to insert multiple records in a `foreach` loop using Entity Framework, first record is inserted successfully, but when I start inserting second record a sql exception occurs, its details say:

> (SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'EmployeeVacation' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.)

I tried this in sqlserver : `SET IDENTITY_INSERT EmployeeVacation ON`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Provide the code which you tried to insert records.

Comment: SET IDENTITY INSERT ON will only work for the current transaction. since EF uses its own transactions per default, you'll have to use your own transactions. However, if the first round works, it is possible that id values of other entries have been set, in which case the insert statement might fail when you try to insert values with already existing PK values.